# Group by in .net core 3.1

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am trying to group by 2 fields and than count rows of each status.
I am using .NET core 3.1 and newest version of EF.

I am getting an error: The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated...

What I investigated so far is, when I get rid off predicate
**y.Count(x=>x.Status == "New")**
and just leave **y.Count()** it works fine.

Orders collection is just a mocked list of objects, in my real app it is a table in sql server.

```
//Rextester.Program.Main is the entry point for your code. Don't change it.
//Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 2.9.0.63208 (958f2354)

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var orders = new List<Order>();
            orders.Add(new Order(){Year = 2020, Status = "New"});
            orders.Add(new Order(){Year = 2020, Status = "New"});
            orders.Add(new Order(){Year = 2020, Status = "Canceled"});
            orders.Add(new Order(){Year = 2020, Status = "Shipped"});            

            
            var result = await orders
                .GroupBy(x=> new {x.Year, x.Status})
                .Select(y => new 
                {   
                    Year = y.Key.Year,
                    NewCount = y.Count(x=>x.Status == "New"),
                    CanceledCount = y.Count(x=>x.Status == "Canceled"),
                    ShippedCount = y.Count(x=>x.Status == "Shipped")                          
                }).ToListAsync();
        }
    }
    public class Order
    {
        public int Year {get;set;}
        public string Status {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Expected result is:

Year: 2020, NewCount: 2

Year: 2020, CanceledCount : 1

Year: 2020, ShippedCount : 1

What am I doing wrong? How to correct this error to get desired output?

EDIT: This is my playground https://dotnetfiddle.net/v7IYmq

Comment: The code you posted won't throw that exception. That exception is only thrown when using EF Core with a query that *can't* be translated to SQL, typically because it uses client-side functions

Comment: Post the *actual* code, and *actual* exception.

Comment: This is actual code, the only change is that I am calling injeted dbcontext instead of mocked list.

Comment: BTW the expressions `y.Count(x=>x.Status == "New")` etc are meaningless in SQL. A GROUP BY and COUNT will return single count values. There's no enumerable to filter any more. The `status` is part of the key anyway.

Comment: `the only change is that I am calling injeted dbcontext instead of mocked list.` that's not "only". This is now a **completely** different method. What you posted simply filters lists in memory without issues. When you use EF Core though the LINQ query is translated to SQL. And `y.Count(x=>x.Status == "New")` is meaningless in SQL. That's what the *actual* exception says

Comment: Ok, brother, I think I understand now, let me check :)

Comment: It looks like you tried to "pivot" the GROUP BY results by copying code meant for Enumerable<T> only. This won't work with EF Core. I answered an almost identical question 30 minutes ago. Convert the results to a `Dictionary<>` with `ToDictionary(g=>g.Key,g=>g.Count())` and retrieve individual key values

Comment: You are right, there is no reason to filter already filtered results. This is where an exception came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following. You are already grouping by Year and Status. Status is part of your key so you can use that to your advantage. Then just count the records using `y.Count()`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var orders = new List<Order>();
            orders.Add(new Order(){Year = 2020, Status = "New"});
            orders.Add(new Order(){Year = 2020, Status = "New"});
            orders.Add(new Order(){Year = 2020, Status = "Canceled"});
            orders.Add(new Order(){Year = 2020, Status = "Shipped"});            

            
            var result = orders
                .GroupBy(x=> new {x.Year, x.Status})
                .Select(y => new 
                {   
                    Year = y.Key.Year,
                    Status = y.Key.Status,
                    Count = y.Count()                      
                }).ToList();
            foreach (var item in result)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1} {2}",item.Year,item.Status, item.Count));
                }
        }
    }
    public class Order
    {
        public int Year {get;set;}
        public string Status {get;set;}
    }
```

Comment: Using a `List<>` with LINQ will never throw the exception posted in the question. The posted pseudocode, not the actual code

Comment: Yeah. I cannot replicate the error they have but was just focusing on the behavior of the code towards the output.